# Replacing Lubuntu with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu 16.04, and noticed quite a few bugs. I want to remove this OS, and put Ubuntu 14.04 on instead.

When giving the Linux partition back to Windows, I understand that you need to put the Windows 10 .iso onto a flash drive, and repair Windows from there.

However, I don't want to give the partition back to Windows. I want to delete the Lubuntu volumes from disk manager, leave it unallocated, and put Ubuntu in it's place. Is this possible? Or do I have to give the partition back to Windows, then re-partition it for Ubuntu, and then install Ubuntu in the re-created unallocated disk space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite possible.  Boot from a live USB and do a Something Else install.  Mark the partitions you already have used for Lubuntu to be used for Ubuntu : if you did a default install, you probably just have a system partition and a swap partition.  Mark the system partition to be used, mounted at /, and formatted.

Comment: This was my plan: I was going to go into Windows Disk manager, delete partitions --> this would leave me with unallocated partitions again. I would then install Ubuntu as usual, and be done. Is it that easy? Or will deleting the partitions cause some boot issues?

Comment: You don't even need to do anything in windows.  If you proceed as I outlined above using the live USB, it will format the Lubuntu system partition and install Ubuntu over it.  Just be SURE you pick the right partition.  It should be formatted ext4, NOT nfts.  I always suggest having good backups before doing any of this.

Comment: Don't touch any of the Windows partitions!

Comment: haha I know, I have to be super careful!